# Непонятный код с variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть код, который, используя *variadic templates*, печатает любое количество входных аргументов в поток:

```
template<typename...Args>
void print(Args&& ...args) {
    char compile_time_buffer[sizeof...(Args)] = {
    ((std::cout << args <<" "), 0)...
};
std::cout<< "\n";
}
```

Совершенно не могу понять, чем инициализируется массив `compile_time_buffer`. Что скрывается за синтаксисом `((std::cout << args <<" "), 0)`? И почему массив `char`, а в поток корректно выводятся объекты любого типа?

Comment: Если это вопрос чисто об обычном сишном операторе "запятая", то непонятно зачем нужен такой навороченный пример с variadic templates, в котором этот оператор практически не видно...

Comment: @AnT допускаю, что автор просто первый раз столкнулся с "запятой" именно в этом примере. Если бы он нашел ее применение в других контекстах, то и код в вопросе был бы другой.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В этом выражении

```
((std::cout << args <<" "), 0)...
```

используется оператор запятая. Значением выражения является второй операнд после запятой, то есть 0. В результате символьный массив инициализируется нулями. При этом имеется побочный эффект вычисления первого операнда оператора запятая в виде вывода в поток переданных в функцию аргументов.

Чтобы было более наглядно, то просто замените 0, например, на символ 'A'. Ниже показана демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...Args>
void print( Args && ...args )
{
    char compile_time_buffer[sizeof...(Args)] = 
    {
        ( (std::cout << args <<" "), 'A' )...
    };

    std::cout.write( compile_time_buffer, sizeof...(Args) );
}

int main() 
{
    print( 1, 2, 3 );


    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль следующий

```
1 2 3 AAA
```

Можно сделать эту программу более интересной. Например,

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...Args>
void print( Args && ...args )
{
    char c = 'A';
    char compile_time_buffer[sizeof...(Args) + 1] = 
    {
        ( std::cout << args <<" ", c++ )...
    };

    std::cout << compile_time_buffer << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    print( 1, 2, 3 );

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль следующий

```
1 2 3 ABC
```

Вот еще один простой пример использования оператора запятая при инициализации переменной

```
int x = ( std::cout << "Инициализация x. x = ", 10 );
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

На консоль будет выведено

```
Инициализация x. x = 10
```

Comment: хм, т.е. первый операнд тупо выводится, а инициализация происходит вторым операндом без участия первого?

Comment: @xperious Да, первое выражение перед запятой вычисляется и его результат не используется. Результатом всего выражения оператора запятая является  значение выражения после запятой.

Comment: благодарствую, сам бы не допер

Comment: @xperious Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.:)

Answer (score 2):

В данном примере инициализация массива `compile_time_buffer` через список инициализации с фигурными скобками **позволяет реализовать шаблонную функцию с переменным кол-вом аргументов без явного рекурсивного вызова**.

Подобный пример, озаглавленный как *"Braced init lists"*, можно найти на [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Про действие запятой уже подробно рассказано в другом ответе, я же хочу добавить, что простой тип, такой как `int` или `char` нужен для того, чтобы позволить писать выражения любого типа перед запятой, и добиваться этим самым необходимых (полезных) действий. В данном случае - это вывод на печать. Но если бы тип выражения перед запятой позволял бы помещения его в массив, то запятая и ноль после неё были бы не нужны. В данном случае выражение `(std::cout << args <<" ")` имеет тип `std::ostream&`, а как известно в C++ нельзя создать массив ссылок и объекты типа `std::ostream` не допускают копирование.

Дополнительно имеются некоторые замечания по коду:

- по Стандарту не допускается сужение типа при заполнении массива через `initializer_list`. Т.е. либо `0` (`int`) нужно заменить на `'\0'` (`char`), либо изменить тип массива на `int`. Если бы всё выражение было бы константой времени компиляции, то проблемы бы не было (т.е. целый `0` вполне себе представим в типе `char`). Но из-за того, что левая часть выражения (до запятой) не является такой константой будет иметь место предупреждение.
- Размер массива не требуется явно задавать при инициализации, он будет вычислен автоматически на основании кол-ва элементов в фигурных скобках.
- Как таковой массив по факту не используется (но требуется для правильной раскрутки пакета параметров шаблона), поэтому для исключения предупреждений типа `unused variable` стоит добавить приведение к `void`.

Итоговый [пример](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8tmEPsCbftk71ou7) может выглядеть так:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename...Args>
void print(Args&& ...args) {
    int unused[] = 
    {
        ((std::cout << args << " "), 0 )... 
    };
    std::cout << "\n";
    static_cast<void>(unused);
}

int main()
{
    print(1, "a", 100.500);
}
```

Comment: Сужение типа допускается, когда используется константа, как в данном примере, и эта константа может быть представлена в инициализируемом типе. Так что нет необходимости заменять 0 на '\0'.

Comment: @xperious отмечайте полезность ответа соответствующими кнопками голосования слева от текста.